# Copy all the elements of one list N times in a new list Prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I copy all the elements of one list N times in a new list with simple commands of Prolog without using Maplist,findall or libraries.

for example I ask Prolog's query:

```
?- copy_list([a,b,c,d],3,List).
```

The answer to that query is something like:

```
List = [a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d].
```

Comment: What did you try, what is not working with that?

Comment: I tried recursively to do this and i was getting many lists with same elements inside a list
List=[ [a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d] ].

Comment: hint, take a look at `append/2` https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2

Comment: I know append already I tried and it didn't work

Comment: no, that was likely `append/3`, this is `append/2`.

Comment: That was my code!

`copy_list(H, 0, []):- !.`
`copy_list(H, Reps1, [H|T]):-`
  `Reps2 is Reps1 - 1,`
  `copy_list(H, Reps2, T).`

Comment: Your accepted answer uses the `append/3` library call. That's an acceptable call? It would be helpful to know more specifically what is acceptable and what is not.

Answer (score 2):

We can first generate a list of `N` sublists, and then flatten that list with [**`append/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2):

```
repeat(0, _, []).
repeat(N, X, [X|T]) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    repeat(N1, X, T).
```

so then we can define the `copy_list/3` predicate as:

```
copy_list(L, N, R) :-
    copy_list(N, L, LL),
    append(LL, R).
```

Or we could use [**`append/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3) here, and thus each time decrement the number, and

```
copy_list(_, 0, []).
copy_list(L, N, R) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    copy_list(L, N1, R2),
    append(L, R2, R).
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will use the last one !

Comment: @hellfireworld you said "no libraries" but append is from [`library(lists)`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3).

Answer (score 2):

A twist on Willem's first solution:

```
copy_list(L, N, Copies) :-
    length(Lists, N),           % List of length N
    maplist(=(L), Lists),       % Each element of Lists is unified with L
    append(Lists, Copies).      % Lists is flattened

7 ?- copy_list([a,b,c], 3, L).
L = [a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c].

8 ?-
```

Apologies for violating the OPs original "without using Maplist,findall or libraries" rule. I consider `maplist`, `length`, and `append` fundamental in the Prolog aresenal.

Answer (score 2):

"no `maplist`, `findall` or libraries":

```erlang
copy_list(  _,     0,    []).
copy_list( Xs,     I,    Ys) :- I > 0, copy_list(
           Xs,     I,    Ys,  Xs ).

copy_list( Xs,     1,    Xs,  _  ).
copy_list( [X|Xs], I, [X|Ys], Xs0) :- I > 1, copy_list(Xs,  I,  Ys, Xs0).
copy_list( [],     I,    Ys , Xs0) :- I > 1, I1 is I-1, 
                                             copy_list(Xs0, I1, Ys, Xs0).
```

Comment: s(x)... Dang I sometimes glance right past those comments OPs make about "no libraries", although the accepted answer uses `append/3`. :)

Comment: "although the accepted ..." yep. :/ so you shouldn't have deleted yours either. :)

Comment: this is a very nice solution . I suggest using clpfd in examples : promotion of clpfd is very important for Prolog .

Comment: Using `Xs` and `Ys` instead of `X` and `Y` would contribute much to the clarity of this solution.

Comment: confusing is the growth of arity from `copy_list(X,I,Y)` to `copy_list(X,X2,I,Y)` . It should be either `copy_list(X2,X,I,Y)` or `copy_list(X,I,Y,X2)` .  The original triumvirate of `(X,I,Y)` should be maintained .

Comment: @Kintalken this looks like an exercise aimed at beginners learning Prolog the language. no `maplist`, so certainly no `clpfd` either - just pure basic Prolog. on order of arguments, this uses Prolog more as a functional language (since `I` is ground), so it is natural to me to simulate a "closure" of "outer variable `X`" by passing it unchanged as the first parameter to the auxiliary predicate, so conceptually it's `aux{X}(X2,I,Y2)`. Efficiency says to put the *changing* value as first argument, for indexing; but for beginners clarity comes first.  otherwise, I'd just go w/ lurker's code. :)

Comment: @Kintalken on the second thought, I did incorporate your suggestions, in an edit; thanks. see if it's better. :) it feels somehow heavier, now. it's like a whole production, an actual *code*. before, it was this little thing. I don't know...

Comment: @Kintalken I tried using the `#>` and `#=`, and now `copy_list(X,I,[1,2,3,1,2,3])` works, obviously, but goes into infinite loop if asked for the third solution. to guard against that would make the code even more elaborate and obscure, for a beginner for sure. so yet again it shows that clpfd is not a silver bullet to make Prolog declarative, automagically.